# how to link a video from amazon s3 account into my website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an amazon s3 account. As i am expecting a large amount of traffic to my site i want to put the videos to be placed in my s3 account and stream it up to my website. How can i do that?

Thanks
Prady

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to upload it using the [AWS Management Console for S3](https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3), use that to set its permissions to be publicly accessible, and then just access the usual S3 URL for it:

`http://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/key-name`

Depending on exactly how much traffic you're getting, you can look into using Amazon's [CloudFront distribution network](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/GettingStartedGuide/). That will speed things up for your users, especially if they span the globe.